# Replacement of accentuated characters in a variable

Tags: accents

I would like to replace accentuated characters in a string variable but I am not an expert about programming my own macros in Latex. So, I found a macro here : https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/latex-supprimer-des-accents-96612 that can display a sentence without accent after replacing them.
However, when I try to use a variable as an argument of the function, instead of writing directly the sentence, it does not work anymore.
I post here a minimal exemple :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\def\delaccent[#1]#2{% #1=liste des substitutions
\begingroup
\expandarg\exploregroups\def\temp{#2}%
\delaccent@i#1\delaccent@i\delaccent@i
\expandafter\temp\endgroup}
\def\delaccent@i#1#2{\ifx\delaccent@i#1\else\StrSubstitute\temp{\noexpand#1}{\noexpand#2}[\temp]\expandafter\delaccent@i\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\name}{Michaël}
\newcommand{\nameSA}{\delaccent[{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}]{\name}}

\begin{document}

Name : \name

Try 1 : \delaccent[{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}]{Michaël}

Try 2 : \delaccent[{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}]{\name}

Try 3 : \nameSA

\end{document}
```

The result is here :

[image]

Try 1 works fine, but I don't understand why Try 2 and Try 3 do not work, they give me the word with the accentuated characters. My objective is that Try 3 works. I need it to use it in a more complete document. I would appreciate very much if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set the expansion mode to `\expandarg` which only expands `\temp` once.  When `\temp` is a string that is fine.  When it is a macro, no further expansion occurs, the macro is just returned.

In your example code, you could just replace the `\def\temp{#2}` by `\edef\temp{#2}` to get expansion of this term.